# VS Code extension - subscribe to symbol rename

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, automated-refactoring

How can I subscribe to renaming symbol (e.g. class name) in typescript file?
I tried to `registerRenameProvider,` but I don't want to provide the entire rename implementation just to add some small functionality.

The following code will explain what I want to do:

```js
export function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {

  vscode.languages.registerOnSymbolRenameHook('typescript', ({newSymbolName, symbolType}) => {
    // e.g. rename file if there is only one class inside && symbolType === 'class'
  });

...
```

I also tried to register additional command handler

```js
vscode.commands.registerCommand('vscode.executeDocumentRenameProvider', () => {
  console.log('vscode.executeDocumentRenameProvider called!');
});
```

but unfortunately I can't register additional command hook:

```
Activating extension 'undefined_publisher.custom-refactor' failed: command 'vscode.executeDocumentRenameProvider' already exists.
```

Comment: There's a proposed API for renaming of _files_, see https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/43768 and https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_25#_local-rename-events. But I guess that's not quite what you want.

Comment: Yes, I am looking for a symbol name change (e.g. class name) usually triggered via F2 key. Theoretically, I can listen to changes in all files and use GIT to check with Regex whether there has been a change in the name of the symbol in the specific line. But this is a very heavy overhead. I am wondered that VS Code does not provide such Observables that could make the world a better place (︶︹︺)